# Apache2.4 ReWrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a UCP for my SAMP server, what worked fine with Apache2.2, but now we would like to move onto Ubuntu 14.04 with latest version of PHP and Apache.

But since sites-available using new method (.conf sites) somewhy our UCP not works.

Website: http://ucp.classrpg.net/

Problem, when you click to any link its redirect to a php file, which has been rewrited to .web file in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on 
# anything that contains a dot without a colon should be left alone
#RewriteRule ^[^:]*\. - [L]
# anything that contains a slash without a colon should be left alone
#RewriteRule ^[^:]*\/ - [L]
# redirect to main page
#RewriteRule ^/*$ /fooldal.php [L,QSA]
# anything else is to be treated as a title
#RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /data/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.+).see(\?[.+?])?$ $1.php$2
RewriteRule (.+).web(\?[.+?])?$ $1.php$2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?kliens\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://ucp.classrpg.net/kliens.web [L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#php_value display_errors 1

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value memory_limit 15M

AddType application/exe .lnk

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
IndexIgnore *

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

<filesmatch "\.ori">
deny from all
</filesmatch>
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
deny from 89.132.170.28
deny from 84.2.181.10
deny from 84.3.218.168
deny from 85.67.242.26
```

My ucp.conf file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName ucp.classrpg.net

    ServerAdmin sqpp15@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/usercp
        ReWriteEngine On
        <Directory /var/www/usercp/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are saying that it is *redirecting* to the `.php` extension, but that is not the case. The links are doing exactly what the `.htaccess` file tells them to do... So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you don't have the use of `.htaccess` file enabled in your **ucp.conf** file.

This

```
AllowOverride None
```

Needs to be changed to this

```
AllowOverride All
```

After the change restart apache. Let me know how you come out.

Comment: We fixed, however i just removed that crappy .web redirect, and now its works fine.  Thanks for answers anyway!